# How can I save viewing pdf file on Flutter to Local Storage of the device?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, native

My team is building an app which has lists of pdf included (informational app type). And Users want to download specific file to the local storage and share to other platforms. I am using `localstorage` flutter package to do that. But it is not working.
Has anyone done it before or have similar idea I can rely on?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to download a file, then `localStorage` is not the package for you. That is a package for storing JSON based data.

You can use a package like [download_manager](https://pub.dev/packages/download_manager) to manage and download the PDF files.

Comment: Thank you Joao ! I will try with the package you refer.

Comment: You are welcome. If an answer fixes your issue, please remember to mark it as correct.

Comment: @VikrantAgrahari  If an answer fixed your issue. Remember to mark it as correct, to help future users with the same issue.